# What determines the sign of an image distance?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, lenses

> A lens placed at the origin with its axis pointing along the x axis
>   produces a real inverted image at $x = - 24 cm$ that is twice as tall as the
>   object.
>
> What is the image distance?

Why is the image distance $s' = 24\text{ cm}$ not $-24\text{ cm}$ (actually already given in the question)?

Comment: Use the direction of the light rays from image towards lens or mirror to be +ve direction in any problem to face no further problems.

Comment: .yes the distance can be used as $-24cm$ but just keep the +ve direction same for measuring every distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the distance is a scalar quantity, and therefore an absolute value. So, the image is AT -24cm, but is located AT A DISTANCE of 24cm. So the position is negative, but distance is always positive.

If you want to know the new Cartesian Sign Convention:

http://www.it.iitb.ac.in/ekshiksha/images_light_10/figure_9.JPG

Comment: icic, so in the magnification or lens equation formula, I should be using displacement (vector) right? $\frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{s'} = \frac{1}{f}$ and $m = \frac{s'}{s}$. The the negative value?

Comment: yes, that is what the sign conventions are for